# Find the volume of the solid bounded by $z=\sqrt[4]{x^2+y^2}$, $z=1$ and $z=\sqrt{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, 3d, cylindrical-coordinates

Find the volume of the solid bounded by $z=\sqrt[4]{x^2+y^2}$, $z=1$ and $z=\sqrt{2}$. I have to calculate this using triple integral but the I'm stuck on finding the intervals.

Comment: The solid has axial symmetry, so cylindrical coordinates will be the most helpful.  Write the function equation as $ \ z \ = \ r^{1/2} \ \ . $

Comment: I have written a solution for this problem. However, I'll delete my answer to give the OP a chance to show his work.

Comment: @AlexanderXander - As it currently is, the integration in your deleted solution is over a full cylinder, but the upper limit of the actual region is a curved surface.

Comment: @Paul Thank you for your corrections. I fixed all my answer, it took me a bit of work, but I think it is now correct.

Comment: @AlexanderXander - it looks good now. I figured once the issue was pointed out, you would know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The change of variables to cylindrical coordinates $\begin{cases} x:=r\cos\theta,\\y:=r\sin\theta,\\z:=z\end{cases}$ for $r\geqslant 0$, $0\leqslant \theta< 2\pi$ give the solid bounded by $$z=1,\quad z=\sqrt{2},\quad z^{2}=r$$
Since we have axial symmetry, then
$$V=\iint_{R}\left(\int_{\theta_{1}=0}^{\theta_{2}=2\pi}d\theta\right)dA,$$
where the region $R$ is the projection over the $rz-$plane, i.e.,
$$R=\{(r,z):1\leqslant z\leqslant \sqrt{2},\quad 0\leqslant r\leqslant z^{2} \}$$
Hence, the volume of the solid is given by
\begin{align*}\iint_{V}1\cdot dV&=\iint_{R}\left(\int_{\theta_{1}=0}^{\theta_{2}=2\pi}d\theta\right)dA\\&=\int_{z_{1}=1}^{z_{2}=\sqrt{2}}\int_{r_{1}=0}^{r_{2}=z^{2}}\left(\int_{\theta_{1}=0}^{\theta_{2}=2\pi}d\theta\right)rdrdz\\&=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{5}\left(4\sqrt{2}-1\right)}\end{align*}
or using two-integrals changing the order of integration
\begin{align*}\iint_{R}\left(\int_{\theta_{1}=0}^{\theta_{2}=2\pi}d\theta\right)dA&=\int_{r_{1}=0}^{r_{2}=1}\int_{z_{1}=1}^{z_{2}=\sqrt{2}}\left(\int_{\theta_{1}=0}^{\theta_{2}=2\pi}d\theta\right)dzrdr\\&+\int_{r_{1}=1}^{r_{2}=2}\int_{z_{1}=r^{1/2}}^{z_{2}=\sqrt{2}}\left(\int_{\theta_{1}=0}^{\theta_{2}=2\pi}d\theta\right)dzrdr\\&=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{5}\left(4\sqrt{2}-1\right)}\end{align*}